# Order of elements from coset and Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem (Exercise $3.B.6$ FGT)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I try to solve exercise **3.B.6** from M. Isaacs's book Finite Group Theory (FGT).
I give it here.

> Let $N \vartriangleleft G$ and $g\in G$, and suppose that when $Ng$ is
>   viewed as an element of $G/N$, it has order $m$
>
> 1. Show that there exists $h\in Ng$ such that every prime divisor of $o(h)$ divides m. Here $o(h)$ is the order of $h$.
> 2. If $m$ and $|N|$ are coprime, show that the element $h$ of the first part must have order $m$
> 3. Now assume that $Ng$ is conjugate to its inverse in $G/N$ and that $m$ and $|N|$ are coprime. Let $h\in Ng$ be as in the first part. Show
>      that $h$ is conjugate to its inverse in $G$.

There is a hint to the first  and the third part of this problem. I give it here too.

> For the first part find a cyclic $\pi$-subgroup $C$ such that
>     $NC = N\langle g \rangle$, where $\pi$ is the set of prime divisors of $m$.
>   For the third part, let $x\in G$, where $(Ng)^{Nx} = Ng^{-1}$. Observe
>   that $x$ normalizes $N\langle h \rangle$. Consider the subgroup
>   $\langle h \rangle^x$.

I can do only the first part of this problem. However  I don't understand how to use given hint for the first part. Also I  stuck with the second and the third part. I suggest that we should apply the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem here.
I will be grateful for ideas and hints.

Comment: Here are some hints. Part 2 follows easily from Part 1, because the order of $h$ must be a multiple of $m$. For the third part, it follows from Schur-Zassenhaus that $\langle h \rangle^x$ and $\langle h \rangle$ are conjugate by an element $n \in N$, and then $h^{nx} = h^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for hints. But my question in the first item was how to apply a given hint from the book. I solve it by constructing an appropriate degree $g^k$. Also I solved the second item. However there is another question. Why from  $<h> =<h^{xn^{-1}}>$  we obtain that h and it's inverse are conjugated?

Comment: $(Nh)^{Nx} = Nh^{-1}$, $n \in N$ and $\langle h \rangle = \langle h^{xn^{-1}} \rangle$ imply $h^{xn^{-1}} = h^{-1}$.

Comment: Derek Halt, thank you. I solved every item. Can you explain please how can we use the hint from the book in the first item?